# Two unbounded operators on a Hilbert space whose domains have empty intersection.

Tags: functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

Assume that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are Hilbert spaces. Can we find densely-defined closed unbounded linear operators $S : A \rightarrow B$ and $T : A \rightarrow C$ 
such that the intersection of their domains $\operatorname{dom}(S) \cap \operatorname{dom}(T)$ is not dense?

Can it happen that the intersection is even zero?

Comment: Does the accepted answer from [this mathoverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100373/sum-of-operator-and-adjoint-operator) have what you are looking for?

Comment: @fbg: Thank you for pointing that one out. Yes it does.